# How to create an order without paying for it

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout

I've done some development work for an existing site and I want to test the `Checkout process` but I can't get passed the `Payment` step without actually paying. I want to bypass this for testing purposes. I'm using `Onepage Checkout`

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can by pass payment option without making payment by below mentioned steps.

Option 1

`Admin->System->Configuration->Select Payment Methods from left-> In right panel you will get option "Cash on Delivery Payment"->Select "Yes" from enable drop-down.`

Option 2

`Admin->System->Configuration->Select Payment Methods from left-> In right panel you will get option "Check / Money order"->Select "Yes" from enable drop-down.`

It will let you select COD option while payment and you not need to make payment for it.